# Binomial Random Variable and Backwards Proofs

Tags: probability, proof-writing, binomial-distribution

I need to prove the following:

> Suppose that a random variable has a binomial distribution. Prove that if:
>   $$0\leq k<k+1\leq E(X)$$
>   then:
>   $$P(X=k)<P(X=k+1)$$

Essentially, I prove the inverse, that if $P(X=k)<P(X=k+1)$, then $k+1\leq E(X)=np$. This follows fairly simply from the definitions of $P(X=k)$ and $P(X=k+1)$ when you expand them into "binomial form" and do some cancellations. My question, therefore, is the following: is it legitimate to prove a statement in one direction, then argue that you could solve it in the opposite way by inverting the process you used to get there? In this particular example, all I really did was divide by common factors on both sides of the inequality, so I don't see why this type of argument cannot be made. However, I'm still skeptical of its validity, and perhaps curious about whether or not it's more generally applicable (from the precursory research I've done on the topic, it seems that it is not). Any information regarding this type of proof methodology would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Typo, fixed it.

Comment: If you can justify all steps are valid, I don't see why not. You are basically showing $A \Leftrightarrow B \Leftrightarrow \cdots \Leftrightarrow Z$. The problem only comes when you cannot justify the reverse direction is valid.

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose I'm really asking about the "integrity" of such solutions, as I don't see them employed very often. I didn't know if that had to do with their argumentative structure, or if it was just bad practice.

Comment: I you can revert the process then why not do that. In this case, the proof is equivalent to showing that $np>k+1-p$ which follows immediately from $np \ge k+1$.

Comment: The 'integrity' is definitely there. You probably don't see them as often because of how books are written. Moreover, it is not very common that an implication works both ways, or proving them separately is usually far easier.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That clears it up!

Comment: There's also the issue of style. I've had teachers who actively discourage this type of writing because it supposedly encourage laziness and can lead to false assumptions if you are not careful.

Comment: Yea, that was certainly part of my concern as well. I don’t think I expressed it well, but that’s in part what I meant by the “integrity” of the proof